# Mudar nome do processo

Tags: windows, batch

tenho um script feito no CMD do Windows e queria ver se é possível alterar o nome do processo quando ele for executado.

Exemplo:

Tenho 3 script (1- ler_log.bat; 2 - recicle.bat; 3 - Alarm_alter.bat) quando eles são executados no Task Manager o nome do processo é cmd.exe (por rodar dentro do CMD) porém eu precisaria que cada um deles gerassem um processo com os seus respectivos nomes (pois eles rodam a cada 5 minutos e as vezes travam e tenho que fechar todos e ao abrir configurar todos novamente por causa de 1 só travado)

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso vc pode usar o `PID` dos process o diferenciar eles com o `title`

exemplo :

```
@echo off

set "$title=test2"

title %$title%

tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %$title%" | find /i "console" >nul && echo processus com titulo [%$title%] encontrado || echo processus com titulo [%$title%] nao encontrado
```

saida :

```
processus com titulo [test2] encontrado
```

agora se mudar o title por test23 :

```
@echo off

set "$title=test2"

title test23

tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %$title%" | find /i "console" >nul && echo processus com titulo [%$title%] encontrado || echo processus com titulo [%$title%] nao encontrado
```

Saida :

```
processus com titulo [test2] nao encontrado
```

so bastar fazer um outro bat que vai testar os 3 titulos em loop

Answer (score -2):

Por todos serem em `.bat` não deve ser possivel gerar processos diferente, já que todos são interpretados pelo `cmd`. Sugiro que crie arquivos executáveis `.exe` para gerar processos diferentes. Esse video mostra como converter `.bat` em `.exe`: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4q0lOMxnkI)